# Calling local API (IIS Express) from another computer on the same LAN

Tags: iis-express, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a Web API written in ASP .Net Core 2.1. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.
Is it possible to run the API locally (i.e. run it in debug mode from the source code - I believe that uses IIS Express) and call the API from another computer on the same network? I've tried by calling the API from another PC on the same network , using Postman, and using my PC's IP address on the LAN, but it doesn't work.

Comment: There are posts around the internet on how to enable external access for IIS Express.

Comment: Please share a link